# GetSQLValueString - What is this function for, generated by Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, mysql

What is `GetSQLValueString` for? And if there is a difference for PHP7, what difference does this function make? What happens if I don't use it? Can anyone help me understand this better?

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) 
{
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
            break;    
            case "long":
            case "int":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
            break;
            case "double":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
            break;
            case "date":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
            break;
            case "defined":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
            break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}
```

After that, there is a section that uses this function.

```
if($cod_u > 0){
        $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE usuario SET cod_id=%s, nome=%s, sexo=%s   WHERE cod_u=%s",
            GetSQLValueString( utf8_decode($_POST['cod_id']), "int"),
            ....
```

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_decode()`?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)